# Vue Nuxt nuxtServerInit doesn't load the data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In the Vuex Store, I define `nuxtServerInit()` which doesn't initialize at all!

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import mod1 from './modules/mod1'
import mod2 from './modules/mod2'

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        actions: {
            nuxtServerInit() {
                setTimeout(() => console.log('Hello'), 10000)   
            }
        },
        modules: {
           mod1,
           mod2
        }
    })
}

export default store
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` runs on the server. Is it printing to your command line console? Are you running in `spa` mode?

Comment: No I am not running at `SPA` mode. I am on universal mode

Comment: Even the `axios` doesn't work in `nuxtServerInit()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are calling `NuxtServerInit` from `store/index.js` and you are not in a module mode?

> If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary
>   module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to
>   chain your module actions from there.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below example

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```

more details [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action)